# How to toggle a flag after non-blocking operation is finished?

Tags: python

I want to play a sound in a non-blocking manner and at the same time be able to track if the sound is still playing or if it has already finished playing.

So I have the following code and test:

```
from playsound import playsound
import pytest

class Sound:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.is_playing = False
        self.path = path

class NonBlockingPlayer:
    def play(self, sound):
        playsound(sound.path, block=False)
  
def play_sound(sound, player):
    sound.is_playing = True
    player.play(sound)
    sound.is_playing = False

def test_will_toggle_is_playing_flag_after_sound_is_played_non_blocking():
    sound = Sound(path='drum.aiff')
    non_blocking_player = NonBlockingPlayer()
    play_sound(sound, non_blocking_player)
    assert sound.is_playing == False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pytest.main()
```

The test will currently pass, but this is only because `player.play(sound)` is non-blocking and `sound.is_playing = False` will execute immediately after it.

How can I change the test - and then the tested code - so as to guarantee that the flag is toggled only **after** the sound has finished playing?

I was thinking about calculating the duration of the sound and also using coroutines/async-await to suspend and resume, but I am not sure how to glue these ideas together.

Comment: Looks like the `playsound` package doesn't have an API for this. If you can't use another library that does, you can run a blocking `playsound` call in a background thread.

Comment: I was going to recommend that you just copy the implementation from playsound.py, but I just looked at the source code for and it's a bit of a mess, with completely different implementations for Unix, Windows, and MacOs.  I now agree with @Thomas.  Execute it synchronously in a separate thread.

Comment: OK thanks, but I don't quite get how using a separate thread could help me toggling the flag when the sound REALLY finished playing?

Comment: The thread just does: `playsound(soundfile); finished_flag = True`